# Does GridGain support backup of distributed lock?

Tags: gridgain

So far I know GridGain supports distributed lock. Is distributed lock based on distributed cache? Does GridGain support backup of distributed lock, like distributed map?

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, distributed lock is acquired by calling `GridCacheProjection.lock(...)` method, so it will have as many backups as there have been configured for cache.

However, locks do not have transactional semantics, and it is always more advisable to use cache transactions via any of the `GridCacheProjection.txStart(...)` methods. This way you you still get the locking semantics, but will also be able to commit or rollback your transaction atomically.